# How to use my two mac ethernet ports

Tags: mac, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Usage of Dual Ethernet Jacks (One for LAN, One for WAN)](https://superuser.com/questions/9419/usage-of-dual-ethernet-jacks-one-for-lan-one-for-wan)

Thanks for this, but it doesn't go into quite enough detail... is there a way to route using wildcards?

I have a mac tower at work with two Ethernet ports. I also have two separate work networks. Is it possible to have most things use port one while others such as AIM use port 2?

Comment: Unless you are [near] maxing out one of the ports that will not speed things up. So why try this?

Comment: Some things I cannot access on one network. All our corp sites require that we be on corp network. So I want those requests to go through that port

Comment: You can look at setting up different routing paths, subnets, etc., but I'm so out of my depth on OS X for doing this. I know it's possible, because I've done it with Ethernet and Wi-Fi on Windows, and the same principles apply.

Comment: How about something to do with the search domains in the network settings?

Comment: DNS has nothing to do with routing.  This is a routing issue.  You need to solve it with routing.